# ffmpeg mp4 to hls restrict output chunk size instead of duration

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, video-processing, http-live-streaming

I need to convert `mp4` video `hls` format in which I want to limit the output size of each chunk. I am able to restrict the chunk size to duration but it is not mandatory instead I am interested in size.
I am using below command to convert.

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -strict -2 -preset:v veryfast  -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s 640x360 -start_number 0 -hls_list_size 0 -force_key_frames expr:'gte(t,n_forced*5)' -hls_time 5 -hls_segment_filename 'sample-%06d.ts' -f hls sample.m3u8
```

How can I restrict the chunk size to max 500Kb?

Comment: You cannot limit HLS segments by byte size. Closest approach is to encode CBR video (& audio) stream. At 90 kbps, in your case.

Comment: @Gyan thanks for the info. I just realized even 500Kb would not have solved my problem.